# Karate API - Using regex to match numbers

Tags: regex, karate, web-api-testing

I want to assert the returned values in my response using a regex statement.

```
["num_items": 1000, "num_items": 1111]
```

Currently I have `"#regex \\d(1000|1111)"`.

Which throws the error `"$[0].num_items | not a string (NUMBER:STRING)"`

How can I change my regex statement to assert a number and not a string?

Comment: Please clarify your intention with following details: (a) Give an example of your response or its variations. (b) Do you want to match a number or number-range (like 1000 - 1111)  ? (c) What is the purpose of the capture-group, why do you need to extract the number values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a number those are easier to validate:

```
* match each response contains { num_items: '#? _ == 1000 || _ == 1001' }
```

But you can always do a type-conversion first:

```
* def nums = response.map(x => x.num_items + '')
* match each nums == '#regex \\d(1000|1111)'
```

Refer docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#type-conversion

Comment: This is amazing, thanks Peter! Another amazing example of Karate's capabilities :)

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following regex. Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gS5izV/1) for used regex here. This will create 2 capturing groups containing the values required.

```
^\[[^:]*:\s(\d+),\s"[^:]*:\s(\d+)\]$
```